# Syntax error in order() method using ng-click and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following html code to create an ng-repeat:

```
<td ng-repeat="parentCategory in totalParentCategoriesCount | orderBy :'-Count'">
    <h3>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('CategoryParent{{parentCategory.Count}}')">Kategori</a>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'CategoryParent{{parentCategory.Count}}'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
    </h3>
</td>
```

I wish to add the text `CategoryParent` with the number from `parentCategory.Count` to create a dynamic link.

When inspecting the link in the browser I get the corret outcome which is `CategoryParent0`, `CategoryParent1`, `CategoryParent2` and so on. But when clicking the link I get the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpe…Parent%7B%7BparentCategory.Count%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7BparentCategory.Count%7D%7D
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:450
at $a.throwError (http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:165:141)
at $a.parse (http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:164:6)
at $get (http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:96:122)
at http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:129:290
at http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:10:248
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:280)
at Uc (http://localhost:51976/Scripts/angular.min.js:10:219)
```

On the angular page its says the following:

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 15 of the expression [CategoryParent{{parentCategory.Count}}] starting at [{{parentCategory.Count}}].
```

I have been looking at this answer [AngularJS expression throwing a Syntax error in ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095966/angularjs-expression-throwing-a-syntax-error-in-ng-click) and therefore tried many different compinations in the order() method but I cant figure out how to make the link dynamic without using brackets.

Right now the `parentCategory.Count` is an `int` but I have also tried to parse it to a `string` but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-click` already takes an Angular expression - so no need for the `{{}}`

```
ng-click="order('CategoryParent' + parentCategory.Count)"
```

Comment: Funny how this was the only setup I didn't try. Thank you. I will accept your answer when possible.